Diffeomorphism action on frame bundle
I'm reading Nakahara's book to learn about frame bundles. I have a question about the following claim:
"In general relativity, the right action corresponds to the local Lorentz
transformation while the left action corresponds to the general coordinate
transformation. It turns out that the frame bundle is the most natural framework in
which to incorporate these transformations. If {$X_a$} is normalized by introducing
a metric, the matrix ($X^\mu_{\;\;a}$) becomes the vierbein and the structure group reduces
to O(m)"
(Example 9.11)
If one considers an oriented orthonormal frame, the matrix elements thus belong to the group $SO(m)$, where $m$ is the dimension. Local Lorentz transformations themselves form the group $SO(m)$, so the right action is well-defined. However, a general coordinate transformation locally acts like $GL(m)$. Thus, the left action that the book claims seems to me to be not well-defined. That is, for $g\in GL(m)$ and $s\in SO(m)$, the product $g\circ s\notin SO(m)$. Is the left action defined for any diffeomorphism, or is it defined only for a subset of diffeomorphisms, that act locally as $SO(m)$?

As it stands, the quotation does not make much sense to me. Perhaps you should include more details. Right and left actions of what on what? And how do Lorentz transformations give you $SO(m)$?
